# Poetry import package in test

Tags: python-packaging, python-poetry

I have the following project structure:

```
/
  pyproject.toml
  poetry.lock
  tests/
    test.py
  src/
    my_pkg/
      __init__.py
      ...
```

**test.py**

`import my_pkg`

However, I get the error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_pkg'`. How do I properly import `my_pkg` into `test.py`?

Comment: What's the content of your `pyproject.toml`? Did you specify `{ include = "my_pkg", from = "src" }` under `too.poetry.packages`?

Comment: Have you installed the package into your environment? (i.e. `pip install -e .` in the project root)

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. I needed to add the `from` tag...

Answer (score -1):

My solution was odd.

1. Exit the `poetry shell` using `exit`.
2. Create a README.md (`touch README.md`) on the main package dir
3. `poetry install` (should write: "Installing the current project:")
4. `poetry shell` && `pytest`.

Comment: I think this could be simplified to just `poetry install`
Also if you are using pytest make sure you have installed it as a dependency in the project and aren't using a copy installed globally